# D3 update pie data with zero values

Tags: d3.js

I am updating a pie chart with a dynamic JSON feed. My update function is below

```
function updateChart(data) {
arcs.data(pie(data)); // recompute angles, rebind data

arcs.transition()
    .ease("elastic")
    .duration(1250)
    .attrTween("d", arcTween)

sliceLabel.data(pie(data));

sliceLabel.transition()
    .ease("elastic").duration(1250)
    .attr("transform", function (d) {
    return "translate(" + arc2.centroid(d) + ")";
})
    .style("fill-opacity", function (d) {
    return d.value == 0 ? 1e-6 : 1;
});
}

function arcTween(a) {
var i = d3.interpolate(this._current, a);
this._current = i(0);
return function (t) {
    return arc(i(t));
};
```

When the JSON has 0 values for all objects, the arcs and labels disappear. Exactly what I want to happen.

The problem is when I pass a new JSON after one that was full of zeros, the labels come back and tween etc but the arcs never redraw.

Any suggestions on correcting my update function so that the arcs redraw correctly after they their d values have been pushed to zero?

-- edit --

Lars suggested below that I use the .enter() exactly in the same way as I did when I created the graph. I tried doing this but the results did not change. See new update function below.

```
this.updatePie = function updateChart(data) {
arcs.data(pie(data))
    .enter()
    .append("svg:path")
        .attr("stroke", "white")
        .attr("stroke-width", 0.5)
        .attr("fill", function (d, i) {
        return color(i);
})
    .attr("d", arc)
    .each(function (d) {
    this._current = d
})
arcs.transition()
    .ease("elastic")
    .duration(1250)
    .attrTween("d", arcTween)
sliceLabel.data(pie(data));
sliceLabel.transition()
    .ease("elastic").duration(1250)
    .attr("transform", function (d) {
    return "translate(" + arc2.centroid(d) + ")";
})
    .style("fill-opacity", function (d) {
    return d.value == 0 ? 1e-6 : 1;
});
}
function arcTween(a) {
var i = d3.interpolate(this._current, a);
this._current = i(0);
return function (t) {
    return arc(i(t));
};
}
```

Comment: You need to handle the `.enter()` selection just like you do when you initially create the pie chart.

Comment: Lars I tried adding the .enter() to the update function. It is in the same form as when I originally created the graph. This does not quite do the trick. Did I misplace the .enter() in the update function?

Comment: Oh wait, you're not actually removing the empty segments, are you? Could you please post a complete example somewhere? It looks to me like your initial code should work.

Comment: Lars.. Check out this example. Going between data1 and data3 works great. If you go to Data2 it gets broken http://jsbin.com/OcowibiZ/1/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've actually hit a bug in D3 there -- if everything is zero, the pie layout returns angles of `NaN`, which cause errors when drawing the paths. As a workaround, you can check whether everything is zero and handle this case separately. I've modified your `change` function as follows.

```
if(data.filter(function(d) { return d.totalCrimes > 0; }).length > 0) {
  path = svg.selectAll("path").data(pie(data));
  path.enter().append("path")
      .attr("fill", function(d, i) { return color(d.data.crimeType); })
      .attr("d", arc)
      .each(function(d) { this._current = d; });
  path.transition().duration(750).attrTween("d", arcTween); // redraw the arcs
} else {
  path.remove();
}
```

Complete jsbin [here](http://jsbin.com/upUHECU/1).