# Pie chart won't transition on enter selection - d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to get transitions working on the enter selection of my pie chart:

```
  d3.select(this).append('path')
      .attr("fill", function(d, i) { return color(d.data.amount) })
      .attr("class", function (d) { return 'slice-' + d.data.label })
      .each(function(d) { this._current = d; })
      .transition()
      .duration(9500)
      .attrTween("d", function(a) {
          var i = d3.interpolate(this._current, a);
          this._current = i(0);
          return function(t) {
              return arc(i(t));
              };
      });
```

I'm pretty sure I've got got the attrTween() bit correct as I have the transitions working later on in my code. Just can't get it working on the enter selection. What am I missing ?

http://jsfiddle.net/EuK6H/19/

Comment: Not sure what you're looking for -- it's working fine for me when I click on one of the radio buttons.

Comment: Sorry amended  my question. I want a transition on the enter selection. So when the pie charts first show they're animated in.

Comment: See e.g. [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19933581/d3-update-pie-data-with-zero-values).

Comment: Unfortunately I can't see the difference between that and my code. They both have a transition on the enter selection.

Comment: The trick is to initialise with zero width arcs: http://jsfiddle.net/EuK6H/21/

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I am trying to harmonize your answers to both questions...this and the one you provided a link to in your second comment above. In the other question, the solution was to remove zero-width arcs from consideration but in this question the solution is to actually set the arcs to width zero at startup? Since they both work, I am misreading or misunderstanding something.

Comment: @FernOfTheAndes Yeah, the other question/answer doesn't make it obvious I admit since this case occurs there only when new slices are added. It uses the same technique though.