# Pie Chart with update of angles with transition and interpolate

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I am very new to `D3.js`. I'm currently working on Pie Chart using D3. I have made a pie chart using some tutorials as reference.
  I am working on applications in which i return json data values (through service calls) using jquery
ajax and pass a json object to a `function piechart1()`

Here is my ajax call

```
 var dataset ="";
         $.ajax({    
             type : 'POST',
             url : "/<%out.print(this.getServletContext().getServletContextName());%>/completeRacksAjaxRacksReturn.action",
             data : {selectedSite1:selectedSite},
             cache : false,
             dataType: "json",
             success : function(data){
                 $('#div123').html("");
                                 $('#div456').html("");
                 dataset = [{label : "Avaliable", value : 20},
                       {label : "Shipped", value : 40},
                       {label : "Shipped NR", value : 60},
                       {label : "Shipped Clients", value :90}
                      ];    
                $('#div123').html(piechart1(dataset));                      
              }
          });
```

Here is my div tag in jsp :

```
          <table width="90%">
         <tr>
        <td align="left" class="title" style="padding-top: 5px;font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;font-size: 15px;font-weight: bold;">Synthese:</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td><div class="hidden" id="div123"></div></td>
         </tr>
         </table>
```

I have made a javascript file in which i have made a function `piechart1(dataset)` for D3.js

For now i have used `dummy data`

Here is the jsfiddle url (my work) : [myPieChart](http://jsfiddle.net/GMREH/2/)

I'm trying to make piechart like [targetPieChart](http://jsfiddle.net/stephenboak/hYuPb/)

pie chart is done but i'm stuck at `transition` and `interpolation`.

and How to get `ARC` `startAngle` and `endAngle` from  the json values. So that I can get the percentage of particular arc acquired ?

Could  somebody help me out at exactly which point i'm going wrong ?

Comment: It may be easiest to start from the working example and adapt that.

Comment: @Lars : yes ur right. but the pie chart i made took me 1 week. In my code now i just want to apply transition and interpolation. i tried but can't find out were i'm wrong.

Comment: You need a custom tween, see e.g. [here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1346410).

Comment: Thanks. And yes How to prevent Zero values in pie chart if for a particular text the value is zero (Actually the scenario is the text overlaps if the values are zero). any idea

Comment: See e.g. [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19933581/d3-update-pie-data-with-zero-values).